# Run script with integer arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
from sys import argv 

filename, value1, value2 = argv

print value1 + value2
```

Now, I want the two variables, `value1` and `value2` to be passed as **integers**. Right now when I run this in my command line I would get something like this.

```bash
pi@raspberrypi -/Desktop $ python test.py 2 2
22
```

I want something like this to happen.

```bash
pi@raspberrypi -/Desktop $ python test.py 2 2
4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your arguments to integers.

```
import sys
value1, value2 = (int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:])
```

This of course assumes that your are expecting exactly two arguments which can be converted to integers.

If you ever want to pass an arbitrary number of integers, you can get a list of them with

```
argnums = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
```

Also, if you ever plan to write a serious command line interface, consider using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 3):

Everything on argv are strings. You need to manually convert them as integers, like:

```
value1 = int(argv[1])
value2 = int(argv[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the arguments are received as *strings*.

**What can you do?** Convert them to `int`:

```
value1 = int(value1)
value2 = int(value2)
```